# JQuery - Make my script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a script. It does work! It's just a bit rubbish. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Basically, I have a 5 star rating box. When the mouse hovers over the various parts of the box I need the stars to change.

Currently the stars only change when you move your mouse over and out of the element. I need the stars to change while the mouses within the element. I think the problem is with the event but I have tried a couple and it seems to make no difference.

```
$(".rating").mouseover(function(e) {
    // Get Element Position
    var position = $(this).position();
    var left = position.left;

    // Get mouse position
    var mouseLeft = e.pageX;

    // Get Actual
    var actLeft = mouseLeft - left;

    $(".info").html(actLeft);

    if (actLeft < 20) {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-position:0;');    
    } else if (actLeft < 40) {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-position:0 -20px;');
    } else if (actLeft < 60) {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-position:0 -40px;');
    } else if (actLeft < 80) {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-position:0 -60px;');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-position:0 -80px;');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.Microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    $(function() {
        $.each($('.starHighlight div'), function(i, val) {
            $(val)
                .hover(function() {
                    //TODO: remove hard coded numbers and calculate it based on icon size/number of stars
                    var starShift = (4 - i) * -20;
                    $(val).parent().css("backgroundPosition", starShift + "px bottom");
                }, function() {
                    $(val).parent().css("backgroundPosition", "0 0");
                });
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .starSelector, .starHighlight { width:100px !important; height:20px; background:url(http://front-end-developer.net/examples/star.png) top no-repeat; }
    .starSelector div { cursor:pointer; width:20px; height:20px; float:left; text-indent:-1000px; }
    .starHighlight { background-position:-100px bottom; }
</style>
```

XHTML:

```
<div class="starSelector">
    <div class="starHighlight">
        <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Tested on Firefox, Chrome, IE6, IE7 and IE8.

You probably have to add some sort of click event to keep the number of highlighted stars up when user mouse-out of the control.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's pretty funky but I'd figure I put it here to get feedbacks ^^. I haven't tested it, but it should work.

This being said, how about using pure CSS to do that:

```
<div class="stars">
   <span>Star<span>Star<span>Star<span>Star</span></span></span></span>
</div>

.stars span{
  background: url(not-selected.png);
}
.stars span:hover{
  background:url(selected.png);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with an anchor tag. Does work with span tags.. however this method leads to problems with Internet Explorer 6. Its a really ingenious solution though :D

Comment: @jasons: edited my answer to use spans instead. But I agree that in that case it will not work on IE6. Damn you IE6!

Comment: @rochal even with the edit using spans? Not sure. (I used the anchors to hack IE6, so yeah, it was a hack)

Comment: @rochal: aha, ok, this one was just due to lack of concentration. it's fixed now

Comment: @marcgg: Lies: should be <span>X</span><span>X</span>

Answer (score 0):

The mouseover event is triggered when the mouse enters an element. The event you want is [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/).